# How to merge a edit control column and image column in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, grid

```
 <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" HeaderText="Edit controls"
                            ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/Delete.jpg" EditImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/Edit.jpg" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DashBoard">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_ViewDashBoard" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/dash.jpg"  Enabled="True"
                                    Width="" runat="server"  PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("MsgID", "ResponseMetric.aspx?MsgID={0}") %>'
                                    Text='Send'></asp:ImageButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
```

Instead of having two columns I would Like to display both in same column. Header field can be removed for dashboard, everything under edit controls. How to do that. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<Columns> 
     <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/Edit.jpg" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" ID="btnEdit" />
               <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/Delete.jpg" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" ID="ImageButton1" />
               <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_ViewDashBoard" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/dash.jpg"  Enabled="True"
                            Width="" runat="server"  PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("MsgID", "ResponseMetric.aspx?MsgID={0}") %>'
                            Text='Send'></asp:ImageButton>
           </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>          
</Columns>
```